# Can I drag XCode to the trash if I don't develop in it?

Tags: xcode, osx-lion

I do all of my development in Emacs. I never use XCode. The latest XCode (4.3.3) is installed as an app instead of a bunch of files in /Developer and elsewhere. I had to use it to install the Command Line Tools, but now I want to know: Is it safe to drag XCode.app to the trash if all I want is the command-line tools?

Comment: You can try it and see. You can just reinstall Xcode if it causes problems. Also you could just zip the app bundle up so it's not usable, and then if things go badly you won't have to re-download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can remove XCode. If all you need is the command line tools then they can be downloaded as standalone on the Apple Developer link: https://developer.apple.com/downloads

Comment: ... only if you're a registered Apple Developer, however you can get Xcode from the Mac App Store *without* being a registered developer.

Comment: True! A free account will suffice to get the command line tools, and it's lighter on the package size